# how to convert dateTime type to gregorianCalendar

Tags: java, datetime, gregorian-calendar

I am getting time in string like this "2011-02-27T10:03:33.099-06:00" which is of xml dateTime type. I also have timezone of TimeZone type. How should I convert the dateTime to GregorianCalendar java type in that timezone.

Comment: I think you will find the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240510/convert-a-string-to-gregoriancalendar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java has built in code to parse xml datetimes: use [DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseDateTime%28java.lang.String%29).  that will return a Calendar in the parsed TimeZone.  you can then set the Calendar TimeZone to your desired target TimeZone for whatever you need to do next.

Answer (score 2):

```
sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S");
```

parses everything, except the trailing TZ.

```
sdf.parse (sd);
res168: java.util.Date = Sun Feb 27 10:03:33 CET 2011
```

From the [api docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), I would expect

```
sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz");
```

to be used to read the -06:00 in the end. But I see, that there is either an offset in the form 0700 expected, or with a prefix of GMT for example "GMT-04:00". So you have to insert that GMT-thingy yourself:

```
sdf.parse (sd.replaceAll ("(......)$", "GMT$1"))
```

SDF.parse (str) returns a Date, which has to be converted into a GC:

```
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar ();
calendar.setTime (date);
```

Comment: getting a parse exception when doing this:

   SimpleDateFormat sDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.Sz");
   Date resultDate = sDF.parse("2012-02-27T10:03:33.099-06:00");

Comment: @vjk: Yes, it has to be `resultDate = sDF.parse("2012-02-27T10:03:33.099-06:00".replaceAll("(......)$", "GMT$1"));` with a) inserting the GMT before the time offset and with 3 places for the fraction of Second "SSSz" in the end.

Comment: With Java 7, you can now use "X" instead of "Z" which uses the ISO 8601 time zone format (e.g. -06, -0600, -06:00).

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2011-02-27T10:03:33.099-06:00" )
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplanted the troublesome old legacy date-time classes. Specifically, `GregorianCalendar` was replaced by `ZonedDateTime` for a time zone, and `OffsetDateTime` for a mere offset-from-UTC.

### ISO 8601

Your input string happens to comply with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard format.

The *java.time* classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

### `OffsetDateTime`

Your input string contains an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), but not a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone). So parse as an [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2011-02-27T10:03:33.099-06:00" ) ;
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

If you know for certain the intended time zone, apply a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to produce a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

A time zone is always preferable to a mere offset. A zone is a history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Galapagos" ) ;  
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

### Converting legacy ↔ modern

If you must have a [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) object to inter-operate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, you can convert. Look to new methods added to the old classes.

```
GregorianCalendar myGregCal = GregorianCalendar.from( zdt ) ;
```

And going the other direction…

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = myGregCal.toZonedDateTime() ;
```

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy.png]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings nor java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).