# String to GregorianCalendar

Tags: java, string, parsing, calendar

i have this code:

```
String start = startBox.getText();
String finish = finishBox.getText();

myprogram.addPeriod(start, finish)
```

addPeriod method has 2 GregorianCalendar as parameters, so how to convert the 2 string into GregorianCalendar?

I tried a couple of ways that i read on this site but they don't work with me

startBox and finishBox are 2 JTextField filled with date in this format: YYYY/MM/DD.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page. It may be obvious to you, but it is not necessarily obvious to people reading your question — which language are you using? — Oh, thank you for adding the Java tag (while I was typing).  That will get your question to the right people.

Comment: I think you want to look at the `SimpleDateFormater`, convert to a date, and use that date to build your Calendar.

Comment: Before posting, search for similar questions. This topic has been asked and answered many times on StackOverflow. For example, from almost 4 years ago: [Convert a string to a GregorianCalendar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2331513/642706). Or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/240510/642706).

Answer (score 2):

How about this, the steps are self-explanatory but you want to have a handle on an instance of `SimpleDateFormat` of the pattern in which you have your date.

Parse your Strings to get a `Date` instance and set your specific date to the respective `Calendar` instances.

```
try {

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

    String start = startBox.getText();
    String finish = finishBox.getText();

    GregorianCalendar cal1 = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal1.setTime(format.parse(start));

    GregorianCalendar cal2 = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal1.setTime(format.parse(finish));

    myprogram.addPeriod(cal1, cal2);
}
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The 5th and 7th row give me this error:

"Unhandled exception type ParseException"

and Eclipse suggests me to add try-catch block. I did it but the program doesn't work anyway...

Any other solution?

Comment: @smartmouse either enclose all the lines above within the try block or remove the try catch altogether and eclipse would suggest to add throws declaration on the method. Pick that

Comment: @smartmouse Check the edited code, you can enclose the entire code within your try bock