# problem converting calendar to java.util.Date

Tags: java, date, calendar

I need to create a java.util.Date object with an Australian timezone. this object is required for tag libraries used in downstream components (so I'm stuck with Date).

Here's what I have attempted:

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Sydney");
GregorianCalendar defaultDate = new GregorianCalendar(timeZone);
Date date = defaultDate.getTime();
```

However, "date" always returns the current local time (in my case, ET). What am I doing wrong here? Is it even possible to set a Date object with a different timezone?

Update:

Thanks for the responses! This works if I want to output the formatted date as a string, but not if I want to return a date object. Ex:

```
Date d = new Date();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat();
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Sydney"));

String formattedDate = df.format(d);   // returns Sydney date/time
Date myDate = df.parse(formattedDate); // returns local time(ET)
```

I think I'm going to end up reworking our date taglib.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle calendar TimeZones using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230126/how-to-handle-calendar-timezones-using-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Is it even possible to set a Date object with a different timezone?*

No, it's not possible. As its [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) describes, all the [`java.util.Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) contains is just the epoch time which is always the amount of seconds relative to 1 january 1970 UTC/GMT. The `Date` doesn't contain other information. To format it using a timezone, use [`SimpleDateFormat#setTimeZone()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29)

Comment: Yeah, Date gets a lot of people in trouble because it's really just a timestamp. Whenever you're dealing with Dates like you or I would think of them you're really looking at using some flavour of Calendar.

Answer (score 1):

getTime is an [Unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) time in seconds, it doesn't have the timezone, i.e. it's bound to UTC. You need to convert that time to the time zone you want e.b. by using DateFormat.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class TzPrb {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date d = new Date();
        System.out.println(d);

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Sydney"));
        System.out.println(df.format(d));
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
        System.out.println(df.format(d));
    }
}
```