# Android: Convert from PST TimeZone to our local TimeZone

Tags: android, timezone

I have a time in PST TimeZone (06:00 PM PST).
How can I convert this time to my TimeZone?

I tried with some code, but i can not find a method to convert the time zone.

```
import java.util.TimeZone;


  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

               // my local time zone
              TimeZone mytimezone= TimeZone.getDefault();
              String timezonename=mytimezone.getID();
              String myname=mytimezone.getDisplayName();                         

             //this is for PST
             TimeZone timezone=TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"); 
             String timezonename= timezone.getDisplayName();   //GMT+00:00
}
```

Please help me...

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Check the 1st answer here:

[How to handle calendar TimeZones using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230126/how-to-handle-calendar-timezones-using-java)