# Calendar dayOfMonth off by 1

Tags: android, calendar

When trying to get a string for the current date using

```
DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(calendar.getTime())
```

it keeps returning the wrong day. For example, it is saying today, July 25th., is July 26th. Also when I use it to sat a date picker, I get the day value by using

```
dayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

When the date picker is set, it also shows the day ahead by 1.

To get the calendar I'm using

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Is there something I'm missing?
Thanks

Comment: is the date set correctly in the phone settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine this is because you havent set the timezone to your timezone, and rather than the day being off randomly, the time zone you are in is diferent than GMT (Greenwich Median? Time). Try looking at this example [How to handle calendar TimeZones using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230126/how-to-handle-calendar-timezones-using-java)

Comment: I think you're right... It's showing the same date now that it's 01:22 pacific. I've also changed the code to use Calendar.GetInstance(TimeZone.GetCurrent())