# Apply timezone to Date object

Tags: java, android

```
    Date now = new Date();
    Date then = new Date((long)obj.timestamp*1000);

    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
```

Not very familiar with java, but is there any way to apply a timezone to a `Date` object? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230126/how-to-handle-calendar-timezones-using-java) thread, but this is about Calendar timezones, which i believe is something different?

Comment: If you have the chance at all, use JODA Time instead of Java's extremely messy built-in calendar tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [**SimpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29) to set TimeZone.

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yourformat");   
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault(); 
    sdf.setTimeZone(tz);
    sdf.format(yourdate); //will return a string rep of a date with the included format
```

Answer (score 3):

**`Date` object uses the current timezone by default.** If you are trying to print the time in specific timezone, you may use `SimpleDateFormat` as below:

```
   //put the desired format      
   DateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss Z");
   //set the desired timezone
   formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));

   String formattedNowInTimeZone  = formatter.format(now);
   String formattedThenInTimeZone  = formatter.format(then);
```

Answer (score 2):

`Date` objects do not have a timezone, it is simply a container for a specific moment in time.  If you want to apply a timezone to it, you'll have to use a `Calendar`.  I do it as follows

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime( date );
```

If you're just looking to display the `Date` adjusted for a timezone, then you can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to apply the proper timezone adjustments.

Comment: And how would i apply the actual timezone object to the calendar?

Comment: Do it with `cal.setTimeZone( TimeZone );`.  Typically I'd use `cal.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone( "Timezone String Id" );`.