# How to convert UTC formatted string to calendar in specific timezone?

Tags: java, date, timezone, utc, gmt

I'm trying to convert some string that is in UTC time to a java Calendar object that should be set to GMT-5.

My current UTC string input is this:

> UTC date : 20050329174411

I use this code (I detect the 'pattern' as shown below):

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
Date date = dateFormat.parse(utcDate);
calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-5"));
calendar.setTime(date);
```

I then printed the time like this:

> calendar.getTime()

And I got this result:

> GMT date : Tue Mar 29 17:44:11 EST 2005

I need to support theses date/time string patterns:

```
FORMAT_UTC4 = "yyyy";           
FORMAT_UTC6 = "yyyyMM";         
FORMAT_UTC8 = "yyyyMMdd";       
FORMAT_UTC10 = "yyyyMMddHH";    
FORMAT_UTC12 = "yyyyMMddHHmm";  
FORMAT_UTC14 = "yyyyMMddHHmmss";
```

I would be expecting the time to be set to "12:44:11". I have read a couple of examples and I find date time handling pretty confusing. For me, it's always the same, I get some sort of string formatted UTC and I convert it to GMT-5. I really feel it should be easy!

Ref 1 : [How can I get the current date and time in UTC or GMT in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308683/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-utc-or-gmt-in-java)

Ref 2 : [How to handle calendar TimeZones using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230126/how-to-handle-calendar-timezones-using-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must set the SimpleDateFormat's time zone to UTC before parsing the date. Else, it uses your default timezone.

And to display the date in the "GMT-5" timezone, you should use another DateFormat, with the timezone set to GMT-5, and format the date with this DateFormat. The `toString()` method of Date uses your default time zone to transform the date into something readable.

Comment: I had tried this dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-5"));, it needs to be set to UTC instead?

Comment: The input date is in UTC. So it must be parsed using a date format in UTC. The output date is in GMT-5. So it must be formatted using a date format in GMT-5. You wouldn't use an French translator to read a German text, would you? And you wouldn't use a German translator to write a text in French either.

Comment: I thought that getting the date object from calendar (getTime) was giving me the date in GMT-5.

Comment: A Date doesn't have a timezone. It's a universal instant in time. You can choose to format it using a timezone, and its toString() method formats it using your default timezone, but it doesn't have any.

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

Note that `GMT-5` or timezone offset of `-05:00` hours is a fixed offset i.e. independent of the [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) and type to represent a date-time with timezone offset is [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(20050329174411L);
        OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.of("-05:00"));
        // Alternatively
        // OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneOffset.of("-05:00"));
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2605-05-15T18:52:54.411-05:00
```

If you are looking for an automatic adjustment of timezone offset as per the DST, use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(20050329174411L);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Chicago"));
        // Alternatively
        // ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of("America/Chicago"));
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2605-05-15T18:52:54.411-05:00[America/Chicago]
```

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

If at all you need an object of `java.util.Calendar` from this object of `ZonedDateTime`, you can do so as follows:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(Date.from(zdt.toInstant()));
```

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>