# JAVA : Get a wrong current time

Tags: date, calendar

i try to get the current time like that :

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
String sendingDateAndTime = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()).trim();
```

but i get the GMT time when i want the system time (and not the local time because my software will be executed in several countries so i can use the TimeZone object).

I need to use the date library and the GregorianCalendar library but i get the same wrong result.

Many people have the same problem but all the solution that i saw it's to put hard code like "Europe" or something else in the timezone object.

If someone can help you.

Thankssss

---------------------------- UPDATE ------------------------------------

I tried to use the System.currentTimeMillis() and to give it as parameter to calendar object, but i get the GMT time too

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle calendar TimeZones using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230126/how-to-handle-calendar-timezones-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

How about this for the GMT time?

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

And this for the local computer time?

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

DateFormat will default to the local time zone.  The internal format of a Calendar object is the number of milliseconds past midnight, January 1, 1970, GMT.

Edited to add:  When I run this code, I get my local time.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss z");
    String sendingDateAndTime = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    System.out.println(sendingDateAndTime);
}
```

When I run this code, I get GMT, although the time zone is still my local time zone.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimeZone timeZone = calendar.getTimeZone();
    int offsetFromUTC = timeZone.getOffset(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, -offsetFromUTC);

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss z");
    String sendingDateAndTime = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    System.out.println(sendingDateAndTime);
}
```

Comment: Gilbert : Calendar.getInstance() return the GMT time and not the system time.
getTimeZone("GMT") same result.

Example: now the local time is 15:59 and i get 12:59 (=GMT time)

Comment: Very strange ! Someone said me that this problem is since windows 7, witch OS you have?

Are you check if your local time is not the GMT time ?

Comment: I'm on Windows XP, Java 1.6, and my local time is GMT-4 (United States, Eastern Daylight Time).

Comment: I ran my code on eclipse and it's work i get the good time.
Apparently it's because the old version of Tomcat (4.1)