# How to get calender date from a date field in Java in a particular time zone?

Tags: java, date, datetime, timezone

I have a date stored in a date variable(`java.util.Date`), (say `2015-4-4 15:30:26-0700`) in `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss timezone` format. Now if I try to get the calendar day (i.e. `04 april 2015`) it gets converted to my local timezone and prints the next day(i.e `05 april 2015`). How do I get the calendar day in a particular time zone (say `+1:30` GMT)?
I am using the `getdate()`function from `java.util.Date` to get the calendar day.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/230383/3102124) this is a possible duplicate

Answer (score 3):

> I have a date stored in a date variable(java.util.Date), (say 2015-4-4 15:30:26-0700) in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss timezone format.

No, you have a `Date` variable. That doesn't have any particular format. Ignore what `toString()` tells you - that's just formatting it in your local time zone, in a default format. That doesn't mean the format or time zone is part of the state of the `Date` object - that just represents a point in time.

It sounds like you want:

```
// Whatever pattern you want - ideally, specify the locale too
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
// Whatever time zone you want
format.setTimeZone(...);
String text = format.format(date);
```

Alternatively, if you just want a `Calendar` value:

```
TimeZone zone = ...; // Whatever time zone you want
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(zone);
calendar.setTime(date);
// Now use calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) etc
```

Comment: The dates are being stored in the -7:00 GMT format.
I need to validate some values against those dates.
But when I try to get the calendar date, the date gets modified to my current timezone. Is there a way to by pass that?
Also can I give the timezone as -7:00 or +5:30 (or will  have to search a timezone that matches to the particular value)?

Comment: @LakshitPande: "The dates are being stored in the -7:00 GMT format." Not in `java.util.Date` they're not. In `java.util.Date`, they're stored as a `long` value, which is the number of milliseconds since the unix epoch. I've given you code which will either display the value in whatever time zone you want, or give you a `Calendar` object you can use. It's not clear whether you've tried that code or not, or where your `Date` has come from. Use `SimpleTimeZone` to construct a time zone with a fixed offset - but be aware that that probably won't be useful in many places, as it won't observe DST.

Comment: thanks for the info. I did not properly understand the answer. The comments help. Thanks again. It works.