# What is the easiest way to get a formatted string from a calendar object which respects timezone?

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar, timezone

When I search online about "how to convert a `Calendar` to a `String`", all the results I find suggest to first convert to a `Date` and then convert the `Date` to a `String`.

The problem is that a `Date` is only a representation of the number of milliseconds since the epoch - it does not respect timezone. `Calendar` is more advanced in this way.

Of course, I could call the individual `Calendar.get` methods to create my own formatted string, but surely there must be an easier way?

To illustrate, I wrote this code:

```
long currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Madrid"));
calendar.setTimeInMillis(currentTime);
System.out.println(calendar.getTime().toString());
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(calendar.getTime()));
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
```

While running this code from a machine based in London (UTC+0) at 8:02pm, I got the following results:

```
Wed Nov 18 20:02:26 UTC 2015
2015-11-18 20:02:26
21
```

The last line shows the real hour according to the calendar's timezone (Madrid which is UTC+1). It is 9:02pm in Madrid, but obviously both the native `Date.toString` as well as the `DateFormat.format` methods ignore the timezone because the timezone information is erased when calling `Calendar.getTime` (similarly `Calendar.getTimeInMillis`).

Given this, what is the best way to get a formatted string from a `Calendar` which respects timezone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the timezone on the SimpleDateFormat object and then use `z` ..

```
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Madrid"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230126/how-to-handle-calendar-timezones-using-java) for details on how to handle timezones in Java.

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Madrid"));

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Putting 'Z' in quotes will treat it as a literal.

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

While the other Answers appear to be correct, a better approach is to avoid using java.util.Date/.Calendar entirely.

Those old date-time classes have been superseded by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. The new classes are inspired by the highly successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) framework, intended as its successor, similar in concept but re-architected. Defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. See the [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

## `Instant`

An `Instant` represents a moment on the timeline in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now ( ); // Current moment in UTC.
```

For a given [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) object, convert to an `Instant` using the method [`toInstant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#toInstant--) added in Java 8.

```
Instant instant = myCalendar.toInstant();
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

You can assign a time zone (`ZoneId`) to an `Instant` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "Europe/Madrid" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant ( instant, zoneId );
```

## String Representation of Date-Time Value

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "instant: " + instant + " adjusted into zone: " + zoneId + " is zdt: " + zdt );
```

The java.time classes use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formatting by default when parsing/generating String representations of date-time values. By default the ISO 8601 style is extended by appending the name of the time zone in addition to the usual [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

> instant: 2015-11-18T22:23:46.764Z adjusted into zone: Europe/Madrid is zdt: 2015-11-18T23:23:46.764+01:00[Europe/Madrid]

If you want the ISO 8601 style but without the `T`, either call `.replace( "T" , "" )` on the resulting String object or [define your own formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

The [java.time.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/package-summary.html) package can do the work of determining a localized format appropriate to a particular [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).

```
Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag ( "es-ES" );
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime ( FormatStyle.FULL );
String output = zdt.format ( formatter.withLocale ( locale ) );
```

> miércoles 18 de noviembre de 2015 23H38' CET

Comment: thanks - really interesting! However we are unfortuately constrained to use Java 7 for the moment (JBOSS EAP 6.3)

Comment: @Kidburla Then use Joda-Time until you can move to Java 8 or later. The old .Date/.Calendar classes really are that bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can use String.format() to avoid timezone problems

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

This example gives a result in the format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
String s = String.format("%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td:%1$tM:%1$tS", c);
System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
2015-11-20:44:55
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is an interesting approach, which gives food for thought for other similar scenarios. Thanks for suggesting it! However, I don't think it makes for code that is quite as readable as Kal's answer.