# How to enable timezone in JSpinner?

Tags: java, swing, date, timezone, jspinner

```
JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
SpinnerDateModel spinner_model = new SpinnerDateModel();
spinner_model.setCalendarField(Calendar.MINUTE);
spinner.setModel(spinner_model);
spinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner, "hh:mm a"));
```

I am getting the time with date 1 January 1970 GMT.

How to get the correct year and timezone from spinner?

I think we can use:

```
date = new JSpinner(new SpinnerDateModel(
    new Date(TimeHelper.today()), null, null, Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
```

But, `Date` is deprecated.

Comment: `Date` is deprecated, but `JSpinner` is old, and [according to the spinner tutorial at oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html),  `Date` is still the correct thing to use.

Comment: Perhaps something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230126/how-to-handle-calendar-timezones-using-java) can help